# SQLite: Error with cursor in first run

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

My program works fine everytime you run it except the first one, that dump in the last line of this code:

```
public static SQLiteDatabase db;
private String[] niveles = new String [8];
static int nivelesSuperados = 1, col = 999;
public static Cursor c;
BDhelper dbhelper = new BDhelper(this, "BaseDatos", null, 1); 
db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT nivel FROM Tabla", null);
if (c.moveToLast()==false) { //if there aren't rows to get
    ContentValues nuevoNivel = new ContentValues();
    nuevoNivel.put("nivel", "nivel1");
    db.insert("Tabla", null, nuevoNivel);
    c.moveToLast();
}
col = c.getColumnIndex("nivel");
niveles[0] = c.getString(col);
```

It looks very easy but I can´t find the solution

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?  Also, the provided code isn't well formed...it would help to see the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

When you insert data to the database, it does not affect the query you already have i.e. the `Cursor`. You'll have to query the database again to get a new `Cursor` that contains the data you want. But considering you just put the data, there's not really any point in reading the database for a value you already know.

So, change

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT nivel FROM Tabla", null);
if (c.moveToLast()==false) { //if there aren't rows to get
    ContentValues nuevoNivel = new ContentValues();
    nuevoNivel.put("nivel", "nivel1");
    db.insert("Tabla", null, nuevoNivel);
    c.moveToLast();
}
col = c.getColumnIndex("nivel");
niveles[0] = c.getString(col);
```

to something like

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT nivel FROM Tabla", null);
if (c.moveToLast()==false) { //if there aren't rows to get
    ContentValues nuevoNivel = new ContentValues();
    nuevoNivel.put("nivel", "nivel1");
    db.insert("Tabla", null, nuevoNivel);
    niveles[0] = "nivel1";
} else {
    col = c.getColumnIndex("nivel");
    niveles[0] = c.getString(col);
}
```